# Angular 4 - How to have a unique id value for a tag inside an ngFor loop?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I came across a problem in which I need to have a unique id value for each data row I have inside my `*ngFor` loop in angular 4.

My code goes like this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let row of myDataList">
  <div id="thisNeedsToBeUnique">{{ row.myValue }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming that you have a unique id value inside your object, then you can do it like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let row of myDataList">
  <div [attr.id]="row.myId">{{ row.myValue }}</div>
</div>
```

You can also do it like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let row of myDataList">
  <div attr.id="{{row.myId}}">{{ row.myValue }}</div>
</div>
```

You can also concatinate a string and your dynamic value together like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let row of myDataList">
  <div [attr.id]="'myString' + row.myId">{{ row.myValue }}</div>
</div>
<!-- Or -->
<div *ngFor="let row of myDataList">
  <div attr.id="myString{{row.myId}}">{{ row.myValue }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the index to generate unique id

```
<div *ngFor="let row of myDataList; let i = index">
  <div [attr.id]="row.myValue + i">{{ row.myValue }}</div>
</div>
```