# How to stop all items from being opened when editing item in ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array of objects and you can edit the name of each one but then I click to edit one all of the names of the items open, I am wondering how do to fix this.

```html
           <div *ngFor="let stop of fave; let i = index" attr.data="{{stop.Type}}">
              <div class="card m-1">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="card-text">
                    <div class="row">
                      <label class="name" *ngIf="!toggleName" (click)="toggleName = true">{{stop.Name}}</label>
                      <div class="md-form" *ngIf="toggleName">
                        <input (keydown.enter)="updateStopName(i, stop.id); toggleName = false"  placeholder="Chnage Stop Name" [(ngModel)]="stopName" required mdbInput type="text"
                          id="form1" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom">
                      <img *ngIf="stop.Type === 'Train'" class="train-icon" style="width: 40px; height:40px"
                        src="assets/img/icon_trian.png" />
                      <img *ngIf="stop.Type === 'bus'" style="width: 40px; height:40px" src="assets/img/icon_bus.png" />
                      <img *ngIf="stop.Type === 'Luas'" style="width: 40px; height:40px"
                        src="assets/img/icon_tram.png" />
                    </div>
                    <label class="col-4 custom-label">Stop</label>
                    <label class="col-5 custom-service-label">Service</label>
                    <div class="row">
                      <span class="col-5 stop"> {{stop.StopNo}}</span>
                      <span style="padding-left:31%;" class="col-6 stop"> {{stop.Type | titlecase}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="panel col-7" (click)="getRealtimeInfo({stop: stop.StopNo, type: stop.Type})">
                        <img class="panel-realtime" src="assets/img/icon_view.png" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="panel col-5" (click)="deleteFav(stop.id, i)">
                        <img class="panel-remove" src="assets/img/icon_remove.png" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

I know its something to do with the index but I am not sure how to write the code to only open the one I clicked on

[image]

As you can see at the moment all of them open any help is very much appreciated

Comment: you need an unique identifier for every item. Now you are using just one variable.

Comment: Can I use the index as a unique id ?

Comment: @ConorDonohoe yes you can, this will help you more [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51241034/angular-4-how-to-have-a-unique-id-value-for-a-tag-inside-an-ngfor-loop/51241059)

Comment: @ConorDonohoe, do you want to be able to open just one at a time, so if one is open and you click another, the one that is open should close? Or do you want to open as many as you want?

Comment: @AJT_82 i want to open one at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to open one at a time, you can use the index and of the item and a boolean. When clicked, set the index value to `toggl` if it's not already assigned, else assign it `null` (so that we can close the opened div on same click), and then show the content you want, when `toggl === i`. Something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let stop of fave; let i = index">
  <label (click)="toggl === i ? toggl = null : toggl = i">Stuff!</label>
  <div *ngIf="toggl === i">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**DEMO: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rgzdcn?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 1):

In your component declare one array

```
hideme=[];
```

In your html

```
   <div *ngFor="let stop of fave; let i = index" attr.data="{{stop.Type}}">
       <a (click)="hideme[i] = !hideme[i]">show/hide</a>
       <div [hidden]="hideme[i]">The content will show/hide</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a unique id value inside your array, then you can do it like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let row of myDataList">
  <div [attr.id]="row.myId">{{ row.myValue }}</div>
</div>
```

Assign an id to your input fields and they will work fine. Right now all of them have same id.

Comment: I have unique ids i can update the data no problem but its when I click the field to update one result all of the other fields in the array open aswell

Comment: @ConorDonohoe can you share it on fiddle or something

Answer (score 0):

Use this code below as an example:

In your component, create a mapping like so:

```
itemStates: { [uniqueId: string]: boolean } = {};
```

Within your on click function:

```
itemClicked(uniqueId: string) {
    let opened: boolean = this.itemStates[uniqueId];
    if (opened !== undefined) {
        opened = !opened; // Invert the result
    } else {
        opened = true;
    }
}
```

In your HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <h1 (click)="itemClicked(item.uniqueId)">{{ item.name }}</h1>
    <div *ngIf="itemStates[item.uniqueId] == true">
        <p>This item is open!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Essentially, each item in your array should have a unique identifier. The `itemStates` object acts as a dictionary, with each unique ID having an associated true/false value indicating whether or not the item is open.

Edit: The accepted answer to this question is very simple and works great but this example may suit those who need to have the ability to have more than one item open at once.